# How to make a Jupyter Docker container use more memory

Tags: docker, memory, jupyter

I'm running a `jupyter/scipy-notebook` Docker container.
I have not restricted the memory assigned to the container with the run command.

However, what I'm seeing issuing the `docker stats` command is that the container is limiting its memory usage to 2 GB (on 16 GB available!), even if doing complex calculations.

How is this possible?

Comment: Are you using MacOS?

Comment: No, I'm running the Jupyter container from a Ubuntu Server 16.04 machine

Answer (score 4):

Alter the resources (RAM) settings from Docker Desktop - MAC/Windows.

MAC - Docker Desktop

```
Preferences --> Advanced --> Change Ram Settings
```

Windows - Docker Desktop

```
Settings --> Resources --> Change the CPU / RAM / SWAP Settings
```

[image]

Reference: Compiled the solution from @samirko and @Andris Birkmanis. (Added Windows Solution)

Answer (score 2):

I am running Docker on Mac OS and Jupyter crashed when trying to read over 600MB CSV file.
Following Andris Birkmanis instructions helped to tackle the issue by increasing the size of allocated memory for Docker.

Comment: Well, the system does not allow me to comment on others answers and thought it is of general benefit to emphasize the importance of adjusting Docker's memory on Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is going well, by default, docker shouldn't limit by default memory usage at all. So, your `MEM USAGE / LIMIT` doing `docker stats [containerid]` should be the same than your total memory (16Gb in your case), although it's not free but available.

Furthermore, there's no way to set by default a docker memory limit invoking `dockerd`,

So, the only thing I can purpose is specify memory limit in `docker run`

- `-m, --memory="" Memory limit (format: <number>[<unit>]). Number is a positive integer. Unit can be one of b, k, m, or g. Minimum is 4M.`
- `--memory-swap=""    Total memory limit (memory + swap, format: <number>[<unit>]). Number is a positive integer. Unit can be one of b, k, m, or g.`
- `--memory-reservation="" Memory soft limit (format: <number>[<unit>]). Number is a positive integer. Unit can be one of b, k, m, or g.`
- `--kernel-memory="" Kernel memory limit (format: <number>[<unit>]). Number is a positive integer. Unit can be one of b, k, m, or g. Minimum is 4M.`

For more information, please check [Docker documentation run-time options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources)

Check your `docker run --memory-reservation=10g ...`and let's see.

Comment: This answer is very helpful but unfortunately I don't think this is a Docker configuration issue. As you correctly are pointing out, Docker does not restrict the available memory. Even with the parameter --memory-reservation=10g, the container is still using 2GB of memory... I think this is more something related to the configuration of Jupyter itself inside the container, but I can't find the solution

Comment: I don't think it's an Jupyter issue because I've just tested it in my Debian 9 and it takes limit to my 16Gb.

Comment: There is also an engine-wide limit of resources; e.g., using Docker Desktop on Mac, it can be set in Preferences->Advanced.